# Python MySQL pooled connection timeout

Tags: python, connection-pooling, mysql-connector-python

I ran into an issue recently where some code was obtaining a connection from a pool and in certain circumstances the connection wasn't being closed, eventually resulting in a `mysql.connector.errors.PoolError: Failed getting connection; pool exhausted` error. According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html), when closing a pooled connection, this just returns the connection to the pool for re-use:

"To release a pooled connection obtained from a connection pool, invoke its close() method, just as for any unpooled connection. However, for a pooled connection, close() does not actually close the connection but returns it to the pool and makes it available for subsequent connection requests."

The code can be fixed to ensure the connection is closed, but as a general question if a connection isn't closed (returned to the pool), is it safe to assume it will never "timeout", instead remaining permanently claimed and unavailable for use again from the pool? Looking at the [connection pooling source](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/master/lib/mysql/connector/pooling.py) I can't see anything to suggest otherwise

Comment: It's not safe to assume the connection doesn't timeout. However, if the pooled connection is closed, a re-connection will be attempted. See the https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/master/lib/mysql/connector/pooling.py#L557.
So, the `pool exhausted` error that you're getting could be related to something else. Can you share some code? I guess calling `get_connection()` more than the size of the pool can raise the error.

Comment: What I meant by that is that the connections managed by the pool may timeout their connection to the server, but in terms of requesting a connection from the pool, there's no timeout for it to return to the pool for future use. The MySQL source appears to get a connection from a queue, and then return it back onto the queue when it's "closed" - I don't see a mechanism for a pooled connection to "timeout" when idle and return to the queue for future use and figured that `close()` "must" be called on pooled connections otherwise the queue will eventually become empty